# api paypal v2 php ¿como crear una orden con varios productos?

Tags: php, api, paypal

Recibo de un formulario varios productos y quiero cargarlos a una orden de paypal pero me da este error MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON. Entiendo que es por el array que paso en purchase_units.

En la parte de arriba tomo lo que viene por POST, luego con los foreach recorro los array de $numero_boletos y $pedidoExtra y cargo estos a $items, despues paso $items a $arreglo_pedido el cual quiero enviar en purchase_units pero me da este error.

Estoy siguiendo este de un curso de internet desactualizado el cual lo hace con api paypal v1 quiero acctualizarlo en php.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo 'Hubo un error';
    exit();
}

require __DIR__ .'/includes/vendor/autoload.php';
require  __DIR__ .'/includes/paypal.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $regalo = $_POST['regalo'];
        $total = $_POST['total_pedido'];
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        //pedidos
        $boletos = $_POST['boletos'];
        $numero_boletos = $boletos;
        $pedidoExtra = $_POST['pedido_extra'];
        $camisas = $_POST['pedido_extra']['camisas']['cantidad'];
        $precioCamisas = $_POST['pedido_extra']['camisas']['precio'];

        $etiquetas = $_POST['pedido_extra']['etiquetas']['cantidad'];
        $precioEtiqueta = $_POST['pedido_extra']['etiquetas']['precio'];


// .................... Inserta en la bd  ..................................

        include_once('includes/funciones/funciones.php');
        $pedido = productos_json($boletos, $camisas, $etiquetas); //llama a la funcion productos_json() de funciones.php


        //eventos
        $eventos = $_POST['registro'];
        $registro = eventos_json($eventos);

        try {
           require_once('includes/funciones/db.conexion.php');
           $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registrados (nombre_registrado, apellido_registrado, email_registrado, fecha_registro, pases_articulos, talleres_registrado, regalo, total_pagado) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           //los ? son por cada posicion en la tabla
           $stmt->bind_param("ssssssis",$nombre ,$apellido, $email, $fecha, $pedido, $registro, $regalo, $total);
           //las s son por cada posicios q sea string e i por int
           $stmt->execute();
           $stmt->close();
           $conn->close();
           // header('Location: validar_registro.php?exitoso=1');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
    
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

endif;


$client = PayPalClient::client();

// Construct a request object and set desired parameters
// Here, OrdersCreateRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');

$i=0;
$arreglo_pedido=array();

foreach($numero_boletos as $key => $value){
    if((int)$value['cantidad'] > 0){
        ${"items$i"} =[
    [
        "reference_id"  =>  "Pase: ".$key,
        "amount" => [
            "value" => (int)$value['precio'],
            "currency_code" => "USD",
            "quantity" => (int)$value['cantidad']
        ]
    ]
];
 array_push($arreglo_pedido, ${"items$i"});

        $i++;
    }
}
$j=0;
foreach($pedidoExtra as $key => $value){
    if((int)$value['cantidad'] > 0){

        if($key == 'camisas'){
            $precio = (float)$value['precio'] * 0.93;
        } else{
            $precio = (float)$value['precio'];
        }


        ${"items$j"} =[
    [
        "reference_id"  =>  "Extras: ".$key,
        "amount" => [
            "value" => (int)$precio,
            "currency_code" => "USD",
            "quantity" => (int)$value['cantidad']
        ]
    ]
];
 array_push($arreglo_pedido, ${"items$j"});

        $j++;
    }
}


$request->body = [
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => $arreglo_pedido,
    "application_context" => [
        "cancel_url" => URL_SITIO,
        "return_url" => URL_SITIO."/return.php?respuesta=true"
    ]
];

try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
    print_r($response);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["paypal_order_id"] = strval($response->result->id );
    foreach ($response->result->links as $link){
        if ($link->rel == "approve"){
            header('location:'.$link->href);
        }
    }
}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex->statusCode;
    
    print_r($ex->getMessage());

}
```